# Read date range from partitioned parquet file in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I have a parquet file which is partitioned by YEAR/MONTH/DAY.

From what i know, I can read it thay way for a specific date :

```
sqlContext
     .read
     .option("basePath", "file:///path/")
     .parquet("file:///path/YEAR=2015/MONTH=10/DAY=5/")
```

But how can i get all partitions from a start date to an end date ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the whole file (`file:///path`) and then apply a `.where()` filter.

This will also "push down" the filter to the I/O-level and read only the partitions that are required.

Comment: Thanks for your help, appreciate it. 
But, if i want to compare with a date like "2015-01-01", i do need to concat all the columns and then parse it to date, no ?

Comment: Hm, yes. That's right, if you keep the partitioning as is, it will be hard to define an efficient date range filter.
You could partition by a date-column tough.